# How can I generically type variable bindings in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ramda.js

I have a generic interface available to me as such:

```
CurriedFunction3<T1, T2, T3, R>: R
```

I would like to create a const binding that fills in some of those type arguments. Something like this:

```
type CurriedSorter<T> = CurriedFunction3<(obj: T) => any, string, T[], T[]>;
```

When I try to assign a `const` binding this type, however, I get an error:

```
type CurriedSorter<T> = CurriedFunction3<(obj: T) => any, string, T[], T[]>;

const sortFactory: CurriedSorter = uncurryN(3, flip(compose(
  unapply(sortWith),
  uncurryN(2, ifElse(
    compose(equals('DESC'), toUpper),
    always(descend),
    always(ascend),
  )),
)));
```

> Generic type `CurriedSorter` requires 1 type argument(s).

The `const` binding `sortFactory` should be a function with one generic type parameter, to be used as such:

```
sortFactory<MyType>(
  prop('name'),
  'DESC',
  [{ name: 'foo' }, { name: 'bar' }]
) // returns `[{ name: 'bar' }, { name: 'foo' }]`
```

How can I generically type variable bindings in TypeScript? Is there any way to do this with TypeScript?

Comment: What is the type for `sortFactory` ? did you try mentioning the `T` in  `const sortFactory: CurriedSorter<T>`?

Comment: `sortFactory` should be `CurriedSorter<T>`, i.e., accept one generic type to pass to `CurriedSorter`. I am unsure of how to mention `T` in `const sortFactory`, that's what this question is about. When I do `const sortFactory: CurriedSorter<T>` I get an error "Cannot find name 'T'".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a bare `T` in a variable declaration's type because the `T` could potentially leak out of the value through a property. However, you can have a generic *call signature* as part of the type of the variable. Here's a self-contained example since I don't know what you've defined `uncurryN`, `unapply`, etc as:

```
type CurriedFunction3<T1, T2, T3, R> = (a: T1, b: T2, c: T3) => R;

type CurriedSorter<T> = CurriedFunction3<(obj: T) => any, string, T[], T[]>;

type CurriedSorterValue = {
    <T>(a: (obj: T) => any, b: string, c: T[]): T[];
}

const sortFactory: CurriedSorterValue = function (a, b, c) {
    return c;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `generic call signature` here? Does it mean to declare a type which is actually a type of function with generic signature? like `type CurriedSorterValue`

Comment: Right; `<T>(a: (obj: T) => any, b: string, c: T[]): T[];` is a generic call signature (which may be contained in a non-generic type), whereas `CurriedSorter<T>` is a generic type.